# Convert XDocument to string without added /r /n

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

Hello I'm trying to find a way to convert my XDocument to a string so that I can send that back with an ajax call.

So I have a XDocument as following

```
   var xml = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Contract",
                new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                new XElement("child", "Hello World!")));
```

I'm able to convert this to a string doing the following

```
string i = xml.Document.ToString();
```

but but by doing this my xml document comes out as wrong since alof ot /r/n and alot of "/" get added overall. Is there a way to convert an XDocument to string without this added values?

The string I get

```
"<Contract version=\"1.0\">\r\n  <child>Hello World!</child>\r\n</Contract>"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
string i = xml.Document.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Comment: I see some backslashes still get added but I think I will be able to work with that.

Comment: I'm getting backslashes next to double quotes in attributes. Image example here https://i.imgur.com/lshZ0VX.png   how to remove the backslashes \?